# Failed upload of Conan package to Artifactory server when revisions are disabled

Tags: artifactory, conan

Im trying to upload a conan package to a remote Artifactory server. I want revisions to be disabled so I use `CONAN_REVISIONS_ENABLED=0`. However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://<SERVER>/artifactory/api/conan/<SERVER_ALIAS>/v1/files/<PACKAGE>/0/export/conanfile.py
```

If I set `CONAN_REVISIONS_ENABLED=1` the upload works fine. The server is configured for local repositorys (virtual or remote repos does not exists) so the APIv1 should work.

Is there a configuration on the server side that I have missed that might cause this error?

Artifactory version is: 6.13.1
Repository layout is: conan-default

For the background to this question see [this issue on github](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/6087).

Comment: Did you try running Artifactory 6.15.0? I tried to replicate your behavior, but it's working well. Log: https://gist.github.com/uilianries/0e1dea9c7aa67c72a143829af615bb2d

Comment: @uilianries Thank you for checking. I'm unfortnately not the administrator of the artifactory server so I cannot upgrade it.

Comment: No problem, you can run locally, you can try the docker version which is easier to run: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker

Comment: Thanks! Will try this and report back.